# Independence from factors implies independence from the product?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Edited:
If $X$ is independent from $Y$ and $Z$, is it true that $X$ is independent from $YZ$?

Comment: "If $X$ is independent from $X$ and..." ??

Comment: I'm guessing two of the Xs should be Ys...

Comment: Yes sorry :) my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If $X$ is independent from $Y$ and $Z$, is then $X$ independent from $YZ$?

The answer is **no**. A counter example: take $Y,Z$ to be independent [Rademacher random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution) (i.e., they are uniform on $\{-1,1\}$), and set $X=YZ$.

You can check that $X$ is itself a Rademacher random variable, and that $X,Y,Z$ are pairwise independent. But clearly, $X$ is *not* independent from $YZ$.

Comment: To be clear: this answers the question where the assumption is ($X$ is independent of $Y$) and ( $X$ is independent of $Z$), *not* ( $X,Y,Z$ are independent).

Comment: Yes the answer was clear :) it remains false if we assume $X$ independent from the vector  $(X,Y)$?

Comment: You mean $(Z,Y)$? Then my first gut reaction would be that the statement is true. Take the definition/characterization of independence of $U,V$ as "for every measurable and integrable functions $f,g$, $\mathbb{E}[f(U)g(V)]=\mathbb{E}[f(U)]\mathbb{E}[g(V)]$. Then you should be able to check easily that $X$ and $YZ$ are independent, from using that definition on $U=X$ and $V=(Z,Y)$.

Comment: Yes I meant $(Y,Z)$, a typo again... I'll try as soon as possible

Comment: Ok should be: Let $X$ independent from $(Y,Z)$ and pick $f,g$ bounded and measurable, then $\mathbf{E}[f(X)g(YZ)] = \mathbf{E}[f(X)g \circ t(Y,Z)]   $ where $t(y,z) = yz$. Since $g \circ t$ is bounded and measurable, then $\mathbf{E}[f(X)g \circ t(Y,Z)] = \mathbf{E}[f(X)]\mathbf{E}[g \circ t(Y,Z)] = \mathbf{E}[f(X)]\mathbf{E}[g(YZ)]$ hence $X$ independent from $YZ$

Comment: Looks good to me.